# Adjust Spacing Around Bonds in mhchem Using Other Fonts

Tags: fontspec, mhchem

I just realized that the bonds in the `\ce{...}` command get spaces around them in `text-mode`, when changing the documents font using `fontspec` to f.e. `Linux Libertine O`. Due to the spaces, the double bond looks like an equal sign.

The attached MWE demonstrates the appearance of the atom-bond segment when using `\ce{..}` in `text-mode` and in `math-mode` and further when using neat `text-mode` (without `\ce{..}`). As can be seen, the spaces only occur when using `\ce{...}` in `text-mode`.

Is there a way to adjust the spacing between atoms and bonds in `mhchem`, and therefore make it appear like the neat `text-mode` (Or `math-mode` as they are anyways quite the same).

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\mhchemoptions{
  minus-text-sidebearing-left  = {0.14em},
  minus-text-sidebearing-right = {0.22em},
  minus-math-sidebearing-left  = {0.04em},
  minus-math-sidebearing-right = {0.08em},
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \ce{A\bond{-}B\bond{=}C\bond{#}D}       & \ce{A\bond{~}B\bond{~-}C}                    & \ce{A\bond{...}B\bond{....}C} \\
    \( \ce{A\bond{-}B\bond{=}C\bond{#}D} \) & \( \ce{A\bond{~}B\bond{~-}C} \)              & \( \ce{A\bond{...}B\bond{....}C} \) \\
    A--B=C & {} & {} \\
    {}     & {} & {} \\
    \ce{A\bond{1}B\bond{2}C\bond{3}D}       & \ce{A\bond{~--}B\bond{~=}C\bond{-~-}D}       & \ce{A\bond{->}B\bond{<-}C} \\
    \( \ce{A\bond{1}B\bond{2}C\bond{3}D} \) & \( \ce{A\bond{~--}B\bond{~=}C\bond{-~-}D} \) & \( \ce{A\bond{->}B\bond{<-}C} \) \\
    A--B=C & {} & A\rightarrow{}B\leftarrow{}C \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: ce in textmode with spaces around bonds]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust the spacing by setting the `textminus` key:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
\setsansfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\mhchemoptions{
  minus-text-sidebearing-left  = {0.14em},
  minus-text-sidebearing-right = {0.22em},
  minus-math-sidebearing-left  = {0.04em},
  minus-math-sidebearing-right = {0.08em},
  }

\begin{document}

  \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \ce{A\bond{-}B\bond{=}C\bond{#}D}\\ 
    \mhchemoptions{textminus=--} % default : { \hspace{0.3ex} -- \hspace{0.3ex} } 
    \ce{A\bond{-}B\bond{=}C\bond{#}D} 
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Quite amazing that this cannot be found in the manual :D Thanks, worked perfectly fine.

Comment: @lcnittl It is probably not in the manual, because I wasn't sure it was good enough to be public. Now that I see how intertwined `textminus` is with `sidebearing`, I feel I should create a better public interface. So please expect a change with a future update.