Adjust mhchem bond style
I prefer using mhchem where possible (e.g., stoichiometric equations). However, printing of double and triple bonds seems off-centre and too compact. Is there any way to modify (or introduce a new bond style) in mhchem that mimics a similar style to chemfig?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\setchemfig{atom sep=1.75em,double bond sep=2.25pt}

\begin{document}

mhchem: \ce{H\bond{3}H} 
chemfig: \chemfig{H~H}

\end{document}



Part of a solution may be here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405088/245790 ?
